# Core Data Relationships are not migrated (Custom Migration)

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I really don't know where else to search for a solution to this problem. Basically, I've read twice (or more) all documentation and all pages I found on the web about Core Data Migration.

I had to change some names on the Entities (to readability) and also had to change the domain values used in my entities. AFAIK, in this case, I have to make a custom migration because I have to analyze the Input and generate a new Output:

1. I've created the new Model Version (v7)
2. I've updated the Model

   - Renamed existent Entities, Attributes and Relationships.
   - Added/Removed some Attributes
3. I've created the Mapping Model (v6 to v7)
4. I've configured the Mapping Model using Expressions
5. I've created two NSEntityMigrationPolicy (one for each entity)

[image: Models]

The migration is going well for the entities and fields values, but none of the relationships are getting restored during the process.

During the process, the expression:

```
FUNCTION($manager, "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:" , "RecentCallToRecentRecord", $source.recents)
```

is returning nothing.

I have debugged my custom *NSEntityMigrationPolicy* to check if the Source and Destination Entities are bound as expected and something very weird is happing. During the execution of `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` everything is OK, after calling the superclass, I can navigate from Source to Destination (and the other way around). But during the execution of `createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` this objects navigation does not work anymore.

Thanks in advance for any help.